# How to get Points in Python from Box -> Grainsource Node

Tags: python, houdini

I have a box connected to a grainsource node.

[image: Image of Nodes]

The result is that the box is split up in many points.

[image: Image of Points]

Now I want to manipulate them but I'm stuck at finding a way to get these points in some sort of Array or something else, so that I can work with them in Python.

Comment: In a pyhton SOP, you can get those points by using `hou.pwd().geometry().iterPoints()`